# Envelope augmentation function

Tags: python, numpy

I want to realize an envelope augmentation - that is, given an linear envelope defined by an array of y coordinates, get a longer array by sampling more points on the same envelope.

So say I have an envelope of `[0, 0.6, 0.3, 0.4]`, if it augments (linearly) to get a length 10 array it will be `[0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.333, 0.367, 0.4]`. What are some convenient way to do it through packages like numpy? What about non-linearly?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
import numpy as np
n = 3 #number of samples
x = [0, 0.6, 0.3, 0.4]
a = [np.linspace(i,j,n, endpoint=False) for i,j in zip(x[:-1], x[1:])]
a = np.array(a)
a  = a.flatten()
a = np.append(a, x[-1])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.interp](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html)
for this so this works also for cases when you sizes don't match perfectly like `n = 9`.

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
a = [0, 0.6, 0.3, 0.4]
indices = np.linspace(0, n - 1, len(a), dtype=int)
print(indices)
# [0 3 6 9]
print(np.interp(range(n), indices, a))
# [0.         0.2        0.4        0.6        0.5        0.4
#  0.3        0.33333333 0.36666667 0.4       ]
```